# A generic GDI+ error occurs when saving an image

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, gdi+

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int SAMPLE_SIZE = 256 * 256;
    float[] samples = new float[SAMPLE_SIZE];
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(SAMPLE_SIZE, 1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.Length; ++i)
        {
            int c = (int)(samples[i] * 127 + 128);
            bmp.SetPixel(i, 0, Color.FromArgb(c, c, c));
        }
        bmp.Save("result.png"); //A generic error occurred in GDI+.
    }
}
```

The program crashes when saving the bitmap. When I set the `SAMPLE_SIZE` to a lower value, no exceptions are thrown. The same error occurs on x64 and x86.

I tried to save to an intermediate stream, but the same error occurs.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.WriteTo(fs);
}
```

Why is this happening? The error occurs on x64. Could it still be a memory issue? The image dimensions are 65536x1 which is not that large in terms of bytes reserved.

Comment: take a look here https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/ use this so that you don't have to keep large image files in memory

Comment: Thanks. I know about that. However, I'm wondering why this is happening.

Comment: Try `new Bitmap(bmp).Save("result.png");`

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but it's been my experience that GDI-based graphics, and especially bitmap handling, is only fully supported within a 16-bit signed coordinate system. I.e. the max width (or height) of a bitmap would be 65535. This is consistent with JPEG's maximums. PNG can theoretically handle much larger (32-bit dimensions), but it wouldn't be surprising if there's some component shared between the two encoders that assumes the JPEG limit. Sorry I can't dig up the reference at the moment, but I expect it's out there if you look hard enough.

Comment: @cubrr: I have tried that, but the same error occurs.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I used MATLAB to do the same thing, and I managed to save the image with larger width than 65535. After some digging, I think your assumption is probably correct.
If you want, repost the comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference handy, but it's been my experience that GDI-based graphics, and especially bitmap handling, is only fully supported within a 16-bit signed coordinate system. I.e. drawing coordinates are limited to between -32768 and 32767, and the max width (or height) of a bitmap would be 65535 (since dimensions can't be negative). The latter being consistent with JPEG's maximums.

PNG can theoretically handle much larger (32-bit dimensions), but it wouldn't be surprising if there's some component shared between the two encoders that assumes the JPEG limit. Sorry I can't dig up the reference at the moment, but I expect it's out there if you look hard enough.